# Three.js OrbitControls.js - invoking zoom in/out with button - controls.dollyOut() is not a function

Tags: three.js

I am using OrbitControls.js in my scene and it's working great with mouse and touch events.

I would like to add on screen buttons to zoom using controls.dollyIn(scale) and controls.dollOut(scale).  When I implement this I am getting controls.dollyIn is not a function.

controls is global

I am setting up OrbitControls with

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.autoRotate = true;
controls.autoRotateSpeed = 0.03;
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.1;
controls.rotateSpeed = 0.1;
controls.minDistance = 1;
controls.maxDistance = 200;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2 - .04;
controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
```

And triggering the zoom with

```
$( "#navZoomIn" ).click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    controls.dollyIn(4);
});
```

any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Also, is there something similar to dollyIn() but for rotation, so that on screen buttons could trigger rotation left/right/up/down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The Problem is in library. `dollyIn` is a private function of `THREE.OrbitControls`.

We can modify `OrbitControls.js` by putting two public methods in `THREE.OrbitControls`. There is section calls as **public methods**.

```
this.dollyIn = function () {
    dollyIn( getZoomScale() );
    scope.update();
};

this.dollyOut = function () {
    dollyOut( getZoomScale() );
    scope.update();
};
```

You can access these function as shown below:

```
$("#product-container .canv-zoom-in").on("click", function() {
    controls.dollyOut();
});

$("#product-container .canv-zoom-out").on("click", function() {
    controls.dollyIn();
});
```

If you want zoom step to increase, it can be done by

```
controls.zoomSpeed = 3.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to OrbitControls class, or you don't want to manipulate/extend it, you can alternatively fire a mouse wheel event like this:

```js
    //canvas object of my ThreeJS scene/a wrapper around it
    export const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    /**
     * Zoom in and out inside the model
     */
    const evt = new Event('wheel', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
    const zoomInBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.zoom_in');
    zoomInBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.debug('zoom in')
        evt.deltaY = -240;
        canvas.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }));

    const zoomOutBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.zoom_out');
    zoomOutBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.debug('zoom out')
        evt.deltaY = +240;
        canvas.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }));
```

Comment: I was also thinking to do the same. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised. I would think the error would be closer to something like cannot call dollyIn of undefined. I would make sure your scope chain is established with var in the same block as the click definition:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
//... controls setup code here ...//

$( "#navZoomIn" ).click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    controls.dollyIn(4);
});
```

Orbit Controls has rotateUp and RotateLeft. use negative numbers to rotate down or rotate right. There's also panUp and PanLet. Personally I prefer to rotate the camera with a swing animation and when the animation is done I call controls.update(); it's a bit smoother.

Comment: Thanks, I have been atempting to give this a shot but no matter what I do I keep getting controls.rotateUp (or whatever) is not a function

Comment: Sorry I submitted that too quick.  Here is a stripped down version [link](http://webdev5.onthez.com/orbitcontrols-buttons.html)
And another version taking the buttons out of the mix just calling controls.rotateUp() immediately after setting up controls and still getting the same result [link](http://webdev5.onthez.com/orbitcontrols-buttons-test.html)

Comment: Same issue, can't get dollyIn() or dollyOut() to go.

Comment: @rankind External access to dollyIn and dollyOut was removed along with  most internal functions. You can only access them via the closures created via the mouse interactions. You can view this change occuring at this revision:  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/9389bbe78d6ed22521892e8fba0c4ec3aedd68de   To do what you need, at the time of this writing, you can safely use the older r74 orbitControls with r80+. The r74 orbit controsl is found at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ff4a4b59a965a453755e2177af8e486101c75f8b/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Comment: @WestLangley please see the above comment. I am not sure if this is a pull request or what the history is on the thinking around this change. It could be added as a property at instantiation of the class to bundle the functions for external access?

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to solve my issue using the zoom property.