# can i simulate mousewheel up or down with javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, zooming, mousewheel

I have a web app where with an immersive view. In this view, i can zoom in or zoom out with the mouse wheel action.

What i would like to do is to create 2 buttons which call javascript function and simulate the mouse wheel actions.
I tried with :

```
window.scrollTo(0,300);
```

but scrolling in my case doesn't zoom (seems like only mouse wheel action work).

Do you have any idea, how can i simulate the mouse wheel up or down within the javascript ?

thank you

Answer (score 16):

So i solve my problem after some research.

Here is what i did :

I create a mouse event and pass it wheel event.

```
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initEvent('wheel', true, true);
```

Then i can set deltaY depending on if you want a wheel up or a wheel down.

```
evt.deltaY = +120;
// evt.deltaY = -120
```

And you can pass this event to your element by doing so :

```
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: This used to work in Chrome up to version 49 (April 2016). Now it's just an anecdote.

Comment: Hello. I tried using your solution but i got error undefined on CHrome

Comment: Thanks. Working for me on Firefox 101 and Chrome 102.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an Answer on firing a wheel event now, as `initEvent` is deprecated:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72525302/16054918

You could adapt it to your needs or make the function more general.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `$.animate()` from JQuery. Here's an example:

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 1000, function() {
   // Do something when animation is complete
});
```

Where `target` can be any DOM element you may want to scroll to or a number that determines the length to scroll.

You should check out http://api.jquery.com/animate for more information on this method.

Comment: That's doesn't work, scroll animation doesn't zoom on my view. I think i should create a mousewheelevent and set wheelDeltaY or something like that

Comment: @Sambo Ok, I've just seen you want to actually -zoom in- with mouse scroll, yet in your question you show code for scrolling; which is why it was confusing.

Comment: Thanks, i just found a solution to my problem. So i create a mouseevent 
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
 evt.initEvent('wheel', true, true);
    if (direction === 'in') {
      evt.deltaY = -120;
    } else {
      evt.deltaY = 120;
    } 
and then pass it to my element with 
element.dispatchEvent(evt);

Comment: Sweet! Answer your own question so this gets stored for future questions about this.